# A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. Value: [Function register]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I just now installed redux-persist in my react-native app. And I'm getting this error

" A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. Value: [Function register]
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {"register": [Function register], "rehydrate": [Function rehydrate], "type": "persist/PERSIST"} "

Store.js

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import CityReducer from './reducers/CityReducer';
import FavouritesReducer from './reducers/FavouritesReducer';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['favouriteData'],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  cityData: CityReducer,
  favouriteData: FavouritesReducer,
});

let composeEnhancers = compose;

if (__DEV__) {
  composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  enhancer: composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)),
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {store, persistor};
export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store, persistor} from './redux/store';
import DrawerNavigator from './navigation/DrawerNavigator';
Icon.loadFont().then();

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <NavigationContainer style={style.container}>
          <DrawerNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
export default App;
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quoting from [use with Redux Persist in the RTK Docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist):

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import App from './App'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

let persistor = persistStore(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Also, you don't need that middleware enhancer with the devtools and thunk. All of that is already set up by `configureStore`.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add the `middleware` property even though I don't have any.

Before:

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});
```

After:

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: []
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this not remove the default middleware as well?

Comment: Yep! If you add a middleware property it also overrides the default middleware. I'm running into the same problem and I would solve it without other dep, but I don't think setting middleware to empty list could be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your token is not expired,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35735699)